# woocommerce ups shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ups, woothemes

So first I'll say the plugin works fine, returns correct rates and all that perfectly. What I am attempting to do is send to paypal a custom attribute that displays which UPS service that was selected (ground, 2nd day air, 3rd day, etc).

I know the custom attribute is reaching paypal correctly because I tested the code as follows:

```
 $paypal_args = array(
                    'CUSTOM' => "THIS IS MY SHIPPING"
                     );
```

And it creates the "CUSTOM" field and displays the text on my paypal dashboard when I'm looking at the order details.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
  'CUSTOM' => $order -> method_title,
  &
  'CUSTOM' =>$order -> shipping_method_title,
```

I feel like it's should look something like this:
$order -> (whatever variable I'm missing)

Comment: WooCommerce already uses the PayPal "custom" attribute to send the order ID. Not sure you can send multiple variables.

Comment: My cart wasn't sending a custom attribute until I set one up as described above.   My order id is coming through using the attribute "invnum".   I check my log going back a few days and noticed that the custom attribute was available and that's when I started looking into adding this field to the information being sent.    thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can see the shipping method at any time with the order information in the WooCommerce backend. But without the Order ID when payment sends data back to your site (via IPN or PDT) it won't know which order to match the payments too. As far as I know you are killing IPN.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding the solution to my problem here just in case anyone stumbles across this issue.

So from the beginning the code was entered in to the following file on the woothemes UPS shipping method plugin: class-wc-paypal-advanced.php

I added the following line:   `'CUSTOM' => $order ->get_shipping_method(),`   and what it does now is it sends a "CUSTOM" attribute to paypal which will read "ups ground" or "2nd day air" in my paypal transaction details.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, Zab Allah!